# Not able to receive data in the handlechange in React JS

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a form in Reactjs where I am expected to collect the information and sent to my API. This  information include, Phonenumber, gender, date of birth and country of birth.
I have written my react handleChange code as follows:

```
handleChange (event) {
    const { name, value } = event.target;
    const { info } = this.state;
    this.setState({
        info: {
            ...info,
            [name]: value
        }
    });
}
```

Then I have written my return function as follows

```
return (
          <CardBody>
            <form name="form" onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>
              <div className="grey-text">
               <PhoneInput
                  placeholder="Enter phone number"
                  value={ info.phone_number }
                  onChange={this.handleChange}
                  error={ info.phone_number ? (isValidPhoneNumber(info.phone_number) ? undefined : 'Invalid phone number') : 'Phone number required' }/>
                <Select
                    value={info.gender}
                    onChange={this.handleChange}
                    options={sex}
                  />

                <DatePicker
                    selected={info.dbirth}
                    onChange={this.handleChange}
                      peekNextMonth
                      showMonthDropdown
                      showYearDropdown
                      dropdownMode="select"
                  />

                <CountryDropdown
                      value={info.nationality}
                      onChange={this.onChangeh} />

              </div>
              <div style={{backgroundColor:"#006400"}}>
                <Button type="submit" onClick={this.handleSubmit} className=" btn-success btn-block"  >Validate Account</Button>
              </div>
            </form>
          </CardBody>
);
```

}
};

When I try compile my project it compiles well but when I try to select any of the dropdowns such as phone number, gender I get the error 
TypeError: event is undefined or  TypeError: _event$target is undefined

I am quite new to reactjs. I have tried looking for answer to no avail . Any help on this will be appreciated

Comment: Did you write the `Select`, `PhoneInput`, and `DatePicker` components yourself?

Comment: Are `PhoneInput` and `Select` custom components?  If so can you post them here as well?

Comment: No, Select and PhoneInput aren't custom I installed them and I included them with import PhoneInput, { isValidPhoneNumber } from 'react-phone-number-input' import Select from 'react-select';

Answer (score 0):

you're getting the error because the `<Select />` will pass the value to the `onChange` unlike the `<Input />` which passes an `event` , one way to get around this it to pass a similar object :

```
<Select
    value={info.gender}
    onChange={value => this.handleChange({target : {name : 'mySelect', value }}) }
    options={sex}
 />
```

( probably the same for the datePicker )

Answer (score 0):

You can simply define any variable in `state`. I defined `selectedOption` and used this code. This should help

```
handleSelect = (selectedOption) => {
    this.setState({
        selectedOption
    })
}
```

and call in `onChange={this.handleSelect}`